# How can i get a variable from different TS page in HTML?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

i'm working on ionic2 and i have two HTML pages (`page1.html` and `page2.html`) 
how can i get a variable from `page1.ts` and show it in `page2.html` ?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere (eg, a server or localStorage)

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa yes ! Local storage works with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `ionic g page` to create your page1.html and page2.html file, then you should have .ts file associated with every html.  You can store variables in that typescript file.  And pass those variables between pages using Ionic's NavParams.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/

Comment: i think the best solution -in my case- is using Local storage (as @SLaks proposed), cause i will need this data in many other views ! and navParams is  only usefull in one view. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a provider for that. Following code to share user's name-

**global.provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalProvider {
    public userName: any;

    setUserName(name: string) {  
        this.userName= name;
    }
}
```

**Page1.ts**

```
import { GlobalProvider } from '../providers/global.provider';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
export class Page1Page{

  constructor(private _globalProvider : GlobalProvider) {}
     this.globalProvider.setUserName('John');
}
```

**Page2.ts**

```
import { GlobalProvider } from '../providers/global.provider';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'page2.html'
})
export class Page2Page{
  public user: any;
  constructor(private _globalProvider : GlobalProvider) {}
    this.user = this._globalProvider.userName; 
    console.log(this.user); // John
}
```